# Как проверить что обьекты равны в Jest?

Tags: javascript, jest

Начала изучать Jest и проходить задания. Одно не пропускает. Не понимаю, как иначе реализовать.

Привела мой код

```
/**
 * Write test to check that objects equal after
 * calling function boo
 */

const obj1 = {
  name: "Test",
};

const obj2 = {
  name: "John",
};
const boo = (obj1, obj2) => {
  obj1.name = obj2.name;
};

describe("Practicing with tests", () => {
  it("objects equal after calling function boo", () => {
    boo(obj1, obj2);
    console.log(obj1 === obj2);
  });
}); // Modify this
```

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "объекты равны"? Если сравнивать имена в `boo`, то поставь не знак равенства, а `===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `expect`

Метод `toEqual` проверяет свойства объекта, а сравнение `===` только ссылки на эти объекты

### Читайте [подробнее](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect)

```js
const obj1 = {
  name: "Test",
};

const obj2 = {
  name: "John",
};

const boo = (obj1, obj2) => {
  obj1.name = obj2.name;
};

describe("Practicing with tests", () => {
  it("objects equal after calling function boo", () => {
    boo(obj1, obj2)
    expect(obj1).toEqual(obj2)
  });
});
```

Можно также сравнить ТОЛЬКО интересующее свойство

```js
expect(obj1.name).toBe(obj2.name)
```

Comment: Можно ли с вами как-то связаться? Есть пару вопросов по этой теме.

Comment: @ЄськінаАннаАндріївна Да можно. Контакты у меня в профиле

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо var вместо const:

```
var obj1 = {
  name: "Test",
};

var obj2 = {
  name: "John",
};
```

и:

```
describe("Practicing with tests", () => {
  it("objects equal after calling function boo", () => {
    obj1 = obj2; // оба объекта одинаковы
    console.log(obj1 === obj2);
  });
});
```

Или, как в Вашем случае надо:

```
const obj1 = {
  name: "Test",
};

const obj2 = {
  name: "John",
};
const boo = (obj1, obj2) => {
  obj1.name = obj2.name;
};

describe("Practicing with tests", () => {
  it("objects equal after calling function boo", () => {
    boo(obj1, obj2);
    console.log(obj1.name === obj2.name); // <<<-------
  });
});
```

Comment: `===` и `==` не сравнивает свойства объектов, а только ссылки на них. А `const` и `var` роли тут никакой не играют

Comment: так посмотрите , что написано